# SQL Logic - Friend request from other direction

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my sample Table:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

id   myid    friendid    
-------------------------
1    3       1
2    3       2
3    2       3
4    6       1
5    4       2
```

Right now i am trying to figure out how exactly to sort this data.
I want to be able to obtain a Friend Request based on the information above.

A little further explanation on the table above: if myid is 3 and friendid is 2, that means 3 is friends with 2, but not necessary the other way around.

1. I only want the data to show request from other users
2. Not when we are already friends. i.e. id, 2 & 3

Using the example table above:
Let's say my current session is 2, that means I have two request from the table, one from 3 and the other from 4. Since I am friends with 3, that won't show up. So the request should only show 4.

I tried to create a logic for this but I am a bit lost.

```
    WHERE 
    friendid = $user_id
    AND
```

Not sure what the other piece in there that would put the logic in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `myid` int, `friendid` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`id`, `myid`, `friendid`)
VALUES
    (1, 3, 1),
    (2, 3, 2),
    (3, 2, 3),
    (4, 6, 1),
    (5, 4, 2)
;
```

this query

```
SELECT
*
FROM
t t_out
WHERE
friendid = 2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t t_in WHERE t_in.friendid = t_out.myid AND t_in.myid = t_out.friendid)
```

will get this result:

```
+------+------+----------+
| id   | myid | friendid |
+------+------+----------+
|    5 |    4 |        2 |
+------+------+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great. I totally forgot how to give another table a nick name when using to grab data and compare against itself twice.